# Query in Azure function stop working after a few time deploy?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm just start using azure functions. Follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function), i modified the code & [deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs) it to my function

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        // parse query parameter
        string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
            .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
            .Value;

        if (name == null)
        {
            // Get request body
            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            name = data?.name;
        }

        return name == null
            ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
            : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + Multiply().ToString());
    }
```

Combine with my code

```
public static int Multipy() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return rnd.Next(1, 10)*rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }
```

The function run successfully when deploy, but after a few times rebuild & deploy again, this show up

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3bpK.jpg)

Remove `name` query & it work as usual

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozFe6.jpg)

Is there something wrong with my code or Azure has limitation for deploy function? How may i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it problem with a query symbol? it is already `?` used so another param should be joined with `&` sign

`{url}?code={someCode}&name={name}`